# Photoshop Text Texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-editing

I wanted to add this "spray effect" to the text but I can't figure out how I can apply it only on the text so the image is not dark.

Basically I would like to know how I can use the layer "Layer 4" only on the text so it does not overlay the whole image.

[I want the text to have this texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeA7Q.png)

[This is how I want to see the image (not dark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXujE.png)

Comment: Lo0ok into layer masks: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=layer+mask+text https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58375/using-mask-to-trace-transparent-space-inside-text

Comment: That works, thanks